# GRASS on QGIS is generating new CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis

I am experiencing a strange problem by using the GRASS toolbox on QGIS 2.14.3 Essen.

Even if in settings>options>CRS I select to use the project CRS when creating new layers, the results of GRASS toolbox tools, like r.watershed and r.fill.dir,  have an "user-defined CRS" with code 100000, even if the project CRS is EPSG 20137.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It is the result of the differences between the [Proj4](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/adindan-utm-zone-37n/proj4/) parameters in QGIS and GRASS GIS:

1) If you look at the definition of the [EPSG:20137 projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/adindan-utm-zone-37n/), the [Proj4](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/adindan-utm-zone-37n/proj4/) string is:

```
+proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=clrk80 +units=m +no_defs
```

2) The GRASS7 commands of the Processing Toolbox use

a) the script */../python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py* to obtain the projection of the layer. In the Python console

```
proj4 = unicode(layer.crs().toProj4())
print proj4 
+proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=clrk80 +towgs84=-166,-15,204,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

b) Then the script */.../python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py* creates the */.../.qgis2/processing/grass7_batch_job.sh* (or bat) file which is processed by the Python module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Beginning of the *grass7_batch_job.sh* file

```
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=37 +ellps=clrk80 +towgs84=-166,-15,204,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1 input="/Users/Shared" layer=line 20137 output=tmp1468150743135 --overwrite -o
g.region -a n=6164723.90083 s=6163210.42107 e=-1860027.15695 w=-1862095.02489 res=100
```

3) If I use EPSG:20137 to create a LOCATION in GRASS GIS

```
GRASS 7.1 (test20137):~ > g.proj -g
name=Universal Transverse Mercator
proj=utm
ellps=clark80
zone=37
no_defs=defined
epsg=20137
unit=meter
units=meters
meters=1
```

And

```
GRASS 7.1 (test20137):~ > g.proj -j
+proj=utm
+no_defs
+zone=37
+a=6378249.145
+rf=293.465
+to_meter=1
```

4) If I use the QGIS Proj4 string to create a new GRASS GIS LOCATION

```
GRASS 7.1 (test_QGIS):~ > g.proj -g
name=Universal Transverse Mercator
proj=utm
a=6378249.145
es=0.006803481196021999
zone=37
towgs84=-166,-15,204,0,0,0,0
no_defs=defined
unit=Meter
units=Meters
meters=1
```

And

```
GRASS 7.1 (test_QGIS):~ > g.proj -j
+proj=utm
+no_defs
+zone=37
+a=6378249.145
+rf=293.4662999999974
+towgs84=-166,-15,204,0,0,0,0
+to_meter=1
```

5) Therefore for GRASS GIS the projections are not formally the same -> your "user-defined CRS" in QGIS.

.prj file of the original shapefile (EPSG:20137)

```
PROJCS["Adindan_UTM_zone_37N",GEOGCS["GCS_Adindan",DATUM["D_Adindan",SPHEROID["Clarke_1880_RGS",6378249.145,293.465]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

.prj file of the resulting shapefile (EPSG:????)

```
PROJCS["UTM_Zone_37_Northern_Hemisphere",GEOGCS["GCS_Unknown",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["Unknown",6378249.145,293.4662999999974]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",39],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

6) The solution ?

You can try to modify the Proj4 string in the file *grass7_batch_job.sh* or in the script *Grass7Algorithm.py* but is easier to simply modify the properties of the layer in QGIS.

Comment: Just one more question... But even if the CRS are not formally the same, are they practically the same? In this case I guess the best solution is to change the properties .If the CRS is not practically the same, the program will read the X coordinate of USER defined CRS as the 20137 one, leading to a mistake... only if the coordinates are the same, changing the CRS in the properties will not affect anything. Let me know if I have understood. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have understood.

Comment: The proj. definition at spatialreference.org is wrong, it misses the +towgs84 parameter. QGIS 2.14.3 and GRASS 7.04 use the correct values. I wonder how you get the GRASS GIS Location without +towgs84 parameters.