# Issue with v.clean (GRASS command) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-grass-plugin, grass-7.1

I've trying to clean topology in certain shapefiles.

When I use `v.clean` command from GRASS 7 in QGIS, the results is a shapefile with a different CRS from original shapefile. Also, when I try to ejecute another commands over `v.clean` output (as `buffer`, i.e), results are vectors with no features.

For example:

I'm working in ETRS89 / UTM 30N by default and without "on the fly" reprojection (1).

Result of `v.clean` (green line) is accord with original vector (red lines)(2).

But when I check CRS in properties (3), it doesn't have one. Also, `v.clean` doesn't save a *.qpj* file with cleaned shapefile, but save a *.prj* file.

Checking the arguments of *.prj* file, it's completely different from original shapefile, project CRS and CRS configuration for new layers (original in top, result in bottom, 4).

Setting projection from properties box doesn't work, I can't ejecute basic geoprocesses over the "cleaned" layer.

I've tried in OS X and Windows QGIS 2.18 version without positive results. Is this a bug of last version or I'm doing something wrong?

[image: issue]

Comment: Look at [GRASS on QGIS is generating newCRS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/201549)

Comment: The solution doesn't solve geoprocessing problem, only CRS in .pjr file. A basic "Fixed distance buffer" doesn't work, the result is a layer with no features. As my question was marked duplicated, can you say me how to solve my problem?

Comment: GRASS GIS and QGIS are very different and you must know GRASS

Comment: And the two projections are the same (one from QGIS, the other from GRASS)